# JQuery Run Function On One Of Multiple Attributes

Tags: jquery, attributes

I have a notifications/inbox page where a list of inbox messages are displayed to the user and I want them to be able to mark each message as being read or viewed with the use of JQuery.  I have this code at the moment:

```
<?php echo "<a href=\"#\" id=\"readLink\" data-note=\"$note_id\" class=\"red\">Mark As Read</a>"; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#readLink').on('click', function()
{
    var note = $(this).attr("data-note");
    jQuery.post("php/note-read.php", {
        note:note
    },  function(data, textStatus){
            if(data == 1){
                $('#readLink').html("Note Read");
            }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

This script works completely fine for the last message shown, i.e. the top first message in a list of say 20, but not for any of the others. Can anyone see a way to make it work on any message in the list?

Comment: Replace id with class as id is for unique elements and why are you checking for data == 1 only? if data is incremented per row it will work for single link

Comment: Thanks @RaunakKathuria - That allows me to run the function on any attribute but now it is marking ALL as read

Comment: this is because you use `$('.readLink').html("Note Read");`, that means to edit ALL links with `readLink` class. See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the decision is to set `class`, not `id`. The code would look like this:

```
<?php echo "<a href=\"#\" class=\"readLink\" data-note=\"$note_id\" class=\"red\">Mark As Read</a>"; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.readLink').on('click', function()
{
    var $link = $(this);    //remember 'this' in a variable...
    var note = $(this).attr("data-note");
    jQuery.post("php/note-read.php", {
        note:note
    },  function(data, textStatus){
        if(data == 1){
            $link.html("Note Read");   //...and use this variable, because 'this' would not be the link
        }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Replace id with the class
- Replace `$('.readlink').html("Note Read");` with this `that.html("Note Read");` so it will only update the selected/click link where that is $(this) before entering post

**Updated JS**

```
<?php echo "<a href=\"#\" class=\"readLink\" data-note=\"$note_id\" class=\"red\">Mark As Read</a>"; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.readLink').on('click', function()
{

    var that = $(this);
    var note = that.attr("data-note");
    jQuery.post("php/note-read.php", {
        note:note
    },  function(data, textStatus){
            if(data == 1){
                that.html("Note Read"); //replace readlink class with this 
            }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: I guess in the case of `$(this).html("Note Read");` `this` will be the jQuery AJAX object, not the link